# Как перехватить ввод текста в bash?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, optional, translit

Хочу сделать нечто punto switcher для ubutu console.

т.е. ловим введенную киррилицу и отдаем на латинице.

пример: 1 вариант

> ~$ ды  // ввод и далее появляется и сразу вылолняется
>
> ~$ ls
>
> ... // вывод содержимого диретории, меняет или нет включенную раскладку в системе  - не столь важно, главное выполнена комманда

Это был возможно самый простой вариант

И чуть по сложнее

пример: 2 вариант

> ~$ ды  // ввод и далее появляется, но есть возможность дополнить и поа без выполнения
>
> ~$ ls

или может уже есть таая реализация,
фича вроде не сложная,
но я еще не видел ее реализации

Как это можно осуществить ?

куда Копать ?

как перехватить ввод и сделать свою обработку ввода bash ?

реально ли сделать вывод результата с возможностью дописать ?

Comment: https://xneur.ru/ - вот аналог punto switcher для ubutu, но вопрос будет ли это работать в терминале для меня не ясен, вроде как да

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/787424/454489

Comment: Возможно натолкнёт на мысли https://habr.com/ru/post/495748/

Comment: а разве  xneur  еще не умер давным давно ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем кто ответил.

Лучший ответ был -

### superuser.com/q/787424/454489 – aleksandr barakin 2 дня назад

---

Изначально была проблема с тем,

что, есть некий часто вызваемый скрипт

и не всегда была нужная раскладка включена

Решение было реализовано через

прописыванием алиасов на кириллице.